# where does laravel look up error messages from?

Tags: laravel

I need some custom validation messages and I looked inside resources/lang/en/validation.php and no matter what changes I made there it had no effect on what I got back from laravel after validation failed.

For example I edited

> 'confirmed' => 'The :attribute confirmation does not match.',

to

> 'confirmed' => 'whatever.',

and when password confirmation failed, laravel still sent me

> The password confirmation does not match.

any idea why its doing that?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: You are in the right file! Tried to use `artisan optimize`?